# Entity Framework should check duplicate records based on unique set of values for few columns and then add the new record

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency, composite-key, unique-key

I've a scenario where multiple API calls are triggered from different clients through some API(sometimes via WebJob), resulting the API code to be triggered in concurrent manner. 
This API code inserts records in SQL through Entity Framework. Due to concurrent calls, the table allows duplicate records to be inserted even when there is a condition to check the existing record. This occurs when there is just a fraction seconds of difference between two calls.

I would like to handle this at Database table level by setting the composite key [no single column can be set as unique] to a combination of three columns, so that SQL will never allow duplicate entries based on these three columns.

However, one of the column for composite key should allow multiple inactive records, but should not allow two entries with active records.

Below example will elaborate the issue :

The red boxed records should not be allowed where the CategoryId and CategoryTypeid is same and both are active.

The green boxed records should be allowed. So if there are multiple records with same CategoryId and CategoryTypeId, only one of them should be active.

Please help in some idea how to design a solution to fix this at DB end.

[image: Duplicated record example]

Comment: Why do you need to store duplicated rows of "inactive records"? Seems they are another key field like timestamp.

Comment: The inactive records are stored for audit purpose. The data is designed to be soft-deleted. I initially thought of moving these records to a separate audit table but can't afford to have all those changes at this moment. Hence have to live with this for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, one of the column for composite key should allow multiple inactive records, but 
>   should not allow two entries with active records.

And what is the problem here?

Define 2 indices.

1 unique index with CatergoryId, CategoryTypeId, IsActive = 1 as filter
1 non unique index CatergoryId, CategoryTypeId, IsActive = 0 as filter

Done.

Filters are the little known fact of indices that most poeple overlook.

ONLY way to GUARANTEE it.

Comment: I wasn't aware if this can be achieved with filter/indices.Can you please also elaborate how to achieve this with help of steps of screenshots/any elaborated way to set this at table level. Does this require alter table command. If yes, should the table be truncated first before applying this ?

Comment: Sure I can. 90€ an hour. This isa Q&A site, i is not there to provide you detailed instructions including screenshots for free. There is a manual, you know. USE IT. I gave you enough hints to find the relevant parts.

Comment: Just saved 90€ :) Found the solution keeping your hints as reference and read through a lot of articles. Posting the implementation of the solution here.

Thanks a lot for guiding me to the right direction !! It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

just to make an idea also can't comment so putting this as an answer. 
maybe you should go trough the union all

```
 select distinct categoryID,categoryTypeID,IsActive from Table where IsActive=1
 union all
 select categoryID,CategoryTypeID,IsActive from Table where IsActive=0
```

this may help you.

Comment: The query is not regarding fetching the records to read, rather the table should be designed to keep the required constrain, so that only one active record can be inserted at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

With @TomTom guidance, I've resolved this issue with below SQL statements.

Created two non-clustered indexes on the table and tried re-inserting the duplicates and got the appropriate error. Creating these indexes makes sure that only one active record can exist in the table.

```
--add unique nonclustered filtered index that allows only one active record
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX unique_active_projects
ON TestDuplicates(CategoryId,CategoryTypeId,IsActive)
WHERE IsActive = 1
GO

--add non-unique nonclustered filtered index to allow multiple non-active records
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nonunique_inactive_projects
ON TestDuplicates(CategoryId,CategoryTypeId,IsActive)
WHERE IsActive = 0
GO
```

Hope this helps someone with a similar issue!